# How can I check video stop or finished in fullscreen mode unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on application in unity3d.
I use

```
Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie(myClip, Color.black, FullScreenMovieControlMode.Full);
```

for play video in fullscreen mode.
So, I need check when video stoped?
I try this snippet code:

```
void PlayVideo(string myClip)
 {
     StartCoroutine(PlayVideoCoroutine(myClip));
 }

 IEnumerator PlayVideoCoroutine(string myClip)
 {
     Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie(videoPath, Color.black, FullScreenMovieControlMode.CancelOnInput);    
     yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
     Debug.Log("Video playback completed.");
 }
```

in this link:
https://answers.unity.com/questions/305407/how-to-check-if-handheldplayfullscreenmovie-has-st.html?childToView=1704005#answer-1704005

but didn't work! actually debug statement executed instantly. it seems code need to modify by add one more line:

```
yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
```

but still didn't work!

Any help please?

Comment: `WaitForEndOfFrame` waits until the end of the currently computed application frame.. maybe it helps already simply adding this line twice?

Comment: try waiting for a second using `yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f)` instead of just for end of frame